# ExpressibleByStringLiteral for DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to conform DateFormatter to ExpressibleByStringLiteral but getting following error

`Initializer requirement 'init(stringLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'DateFormatter'`

I cannot drop `convenience` because initialiser is present in an extension

---

Here is my implementation

```
extension DateFormatter: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public convenience init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init()
        self.dateFormat = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you happy with subclassing `DateFormatter`?

Comment: ya, I had considered that. But I think it would be an overkill